# Get token on the client-side for passport-local authentication

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-local

**EDIT** I tried both, redirecting and not redirecting. When redirecting I get the same result as if I had directly requested `/`, when I don't what I receive is an object containing `data = Moved Temporarily. Redirecting to /`

Given this strategy :

```
var strategy = new LocalStrategy(
{
  session: true
},
function (username, password, done) {
  User.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, user) {
    if (err) { return done(err); }
    if (!user) {
      return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
    }
    if (user.password !== password) {
      return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
    }
    return done(null, user);
  });
});
```

And this server :

```
//************ EDIT ****//
function genuuid(req) {
  return "Test UID";
}
//************ EDIT ****//

var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(passport.initialize());

//************ EDIT ****//
app.use(session({
  genid: function(req) {
    return genuuid() // use UUIDs for session IDs
  },
  secret: "somethingSecret",
  cookie: {maxAge: 60000 },
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: false }));
//************ EDIT ****//

passport.use(strategy);

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/', failureRedirect: '/login' }));

server = http.createServer(app).listen(port, function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
})
```

I'm trying to get the generated token from my client (a mocha test) like this:

```
it('Login should redirect to home and return a user token', function(done) {
  var postData = querystring.stringify({
    username : user,
    password : password
  });

  var options = {
    uri: 'http://' + hostname + ':' + port +  '/login',
    followRedirect: false
  };

  request.post(options)
    .form(postData)
    .on('response', function(res) {
      res.statusCode.should.equal(302);
    })
    .on('data',function(data) {
      should.exist(data);
      should.fail(0,1,'Test not implemented');
      done();
    })
    .on('error', function(e) {
      should.fail(0,1,'Problem with request: ' + e.message);
  });
});
```

Headers contain

```
{ 'x-powered-by': 'Express',
  location: '/',
  vary: 'Accept',
  'content-type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8',
  'content-length': '35',
  date: 'Tue, 08 Sep 2015 19:46:03 GMT',
  connection: 'keep-alive' }
```

There are no cookies or whatever. Where is my token?

Comment: Do you have ```passport.serialize``` and ```passport.deserialize``` functions?

Comment: I do `passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});`

Comment: Hmm.  In the [Passport docs](http://passportjs.org/docs/overview) (search for "deserializeUser") the ```deserializeUser``` function appears to pull the user from the database and return that object instead of calling ```done```, that might be related

Comment: Also, it uses a particular field for serializing the user rather than the whole object: ```passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});```  Notice that **user.id** is used for the second argument to ```done```.  In your case you might use ```user.username```

Comment: I noticed you edited the ```serializeUser``` and ```deserializeUser``` functions; did this have any affect on your issue?

Comment: Nope. For serialize, the docs say `In this example, only the user ID is serialized to the session, keeping the amount of data stored within the session small` so I was just keeping the entire object. Deserialize is not even being called (it's, as I think, intended to be accessed on subsequent requests). So, if I understood the passport's documentation, I am supposed to be receiving the serialized object (the id in this case) as a postdata/header/cookie. But I receive none of them. I will try not following the redirects, just in case

Comment: Just noticed, this line: ```if (!user.password === password)``` will always evaluate to false; instead use ```if (user.password !== password)```

Comment: I corrected that. I thought it was the same as `!(user.password === password)`. I tried without the redirection (and modified the question accordingly), and still no success.

Comment: It looks like there's still an unnecessary ```!``` in that line: ```!user.password```

Comment: The only thing I can think to try at this point is to remove the first ```LocalStrategy``` parameter (```{
  session: true
},```); I've never seen ```session``` explicitly set to true

Comment: I forgot it there while editing the question, it was not in my code. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: It's true by default, but it shouldn't be a problem when explicitly set (it makes sense for what I'm trying to achieve). I tried removing it, but still no luck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using a session middleware for sessions, such as [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session):

```
var session = require('express-session');
// Code to set up your app
var app = express();

// Make sure to replace "somethingSecret" with your own secret value
app.use(session({secret: "somethingSecret", resave: true, saveUnitialized: false}));
```

I wrote up an app very close to the one you provided, and saw the same issue, which was strange for me because I've used express and passport many times before.  When I realized I wasn't using any session middleware, I added the `express-session` middleware and *voila*; `set-cookie` header.

Note, however, that this code is not actually ready for production yet.  From the `express-session` repository:

> **Warning** The default server-side session storage, MemoryStore, is purposely not designed for a production environment. It will leak memory under most conditions, does not scale past a single process, and is meant for debugging and developing.
>
> For a list of stores, see [compatible session stores](https://github.com/expressjs/session#compatible-session-stores).

**[EDIT]**

Using this code (User is stubbed to always return the same values):

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var session = require('express-session');

// Stub of User schema for testing
var User = {
    findOne: function(user, callback) {
        callback(null, {
            id: 1234,
            username: user.username,
            password: 'foo'
        });
    },
    findById: function(id, callback) {
        callback(null, {
            id: 1234,
            username: 'user',
            password: 'foo'
        });
    }
};

var strategy = new LocalStrategy(
{
  session: true
},
function (username, password, done) {
  User.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, user) {
    if (err) { return done(err); }
    if (!user) {
      return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
    }
    if (user.password !== password) {
      return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
    }
    return done(null, user);
  });
});

function genuuid(req) {
  return "Test UID";
}

var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(passport.initialize());

app.use(session({
  genid: function(req) {
    return genuuid() // use UUIDs for session IDs
  },
  secret: "somethingSecret",
  cookie: {maxAge: 60000 },
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: false }));
  
passport.use(strategy);

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});
  
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/', failureRedirect: '/login' }));

server = http.createServer(app).listen(51015, function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Running the test:

```
var should = require('should');
var assert = require('assert');
var request = require('request');
var querystring = require('querystring');

it('Login should redirect to home and return a user token', function(done) {
  var postData = querystring.stringify({
    username : 'user',
    password : 'foo'
  });

  var options = {
    uri: 'http://' + '127.0.0.1' + ':' + '51015' +  '/login',
    followRedirect: false
  };

  request.post(options)
    .form(postData)
    .on('response', function(res) {
      console.log(res.headers);
      res.statusCode.should.equal(302);
    })
    .on('data',function(data) {
      should.exist(data);
      should.fail(0,1,'Test not implemented');
      done();
    })
    .on('error', function(e) {
      should.fail(0,1,'Problem with request: ' + e.message);
  });
});
```

Gives the following output; notice the `set-cookie` header is included:

```
mocha


{ 'x-powered-by': 'Express',
  location: '/',
  vary: 'Accept',
  'content-type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8',
  'content-length': '35',
  'set-cookie': [ 'connect.sid=s%3ATest%20UID.NC0hY3rYGMdnN560ewpf%2FaJbO%2BNd9M7QLz3gnse0eLs; Path=/; Expires=Wed, 09 Sep 2015 13:08:06 GMT; HttpOnly' ],
  date: 'Wed, 09 Sep 2015 13:07:06 GMT',
  connection: 'close' }
  1) Login should redirect to home and return a user token

  0 passing (69ms)
  1 failing

  1)  Login should redirect to home and return a user token:

      Uncaught AssertionError: Test not implemented
```

Except for the stubbed out `User` schema and the hardcoded config values, my code should be the same as yours, so I'm sort of at a loss as to how you aren't getting the `set-cookie` header.

Are you using any other middleware for express that might affect the session or cookies?

**[EDIT 2]**

The problem is that (in your [repository](https://github.com/sieira/sereno)) you are adding the `session` middleware in a different scope than the one in which `server.listen` executes, so the changes made to `app` don't actually take affect.

Instead of having the server start listening before the group of tests, you should have it start *once* for each test, and pass all of the parameters you need into it immediately.  I've submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/sieira/sereno/pull/1) to your repository with the details of how I *might* do this, as it's not a small amount of code and wouldn't really be ideal to paste in here.

Please take the time to read and understand the changes, because I have only been concerned with making the session token be sent, and I make no guarantee as to whether other functionality is affected by these changes.

Comment: I'll give it a try tomorrow. Actually, I'm making some kind of Strategy factory that's intended to add some extra functionality to any given strategy, and I was just testing with the local one as a starting point...

Comment: I tried what is in-between the EDIT comments, and still no luck `genuuid()` is being accessed on each request, but I don't get any cookie in the response. Maybe it is something about the test itself ?. Thanks for your help, by the way. This is starting to get a bit frustrating.

Comment: @LuisSieira I've edited my answer to include the code that I have working. I don't think it's an issue with the test;  I've copied your code almost exactly, and I'm not seeing the issue.  The only things left I can think of are some other middleware interfering with `session` or `passport`, or possibly an issue with your `User` schema, but that doesn't seem likely given that the `generateuuid` function is being called

Comment: @LuisSieira Do have have an open-source repository you can link to in your question?  It would be very helpful if potential answerers could see the exact context in which your server is running.

Comment: Sure, it's here https://github.com/sieira/sereno but it's a little bit more complex than the question

Comment: @LuisSieira I've updated my answer and created a pull request on that repository with changes that should definitely get you pointed in the right direction

Comment: Thats great ! Thank you. Unfortunately, I'm still not getting my cookie. I can't see what changed, since enableSession is changing the same app var than listen is changing... I don't fully understand the javascript scope and closures yet, anyway.

Comment: Try running you mocha command like this: ```mocha --grep "Local Strategy \(With session\)"``` which will just run the test expecting the session

Comment: I think the fact that you're using the same ```server``` var in multiple tests might be the root cause of your issue, so I'm curious as to whether running the session test by itself will produce the correct results or not.

Comment: I'm getting the same results. I will make a minimal test case and keep you up to date. I really appreciate your help

Comment: @LuisSieira No problem; if you get an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ready please edit your original question to include it and I'll post a new answer rather than adding to this one if I can figure out what the issue is.

Comment: @LuisSieira I've updated the pull request to utilize a constructor and properly scope each function; I'm now seeing expected results across all tests